# How to add multiple UIImageView programatically?

Tags: arrays, swift, image

I'm struggling to get all the coupons (UIImage) to show up.  For example, I have 3 coupons, when I run my code, it keeps on showing up the 3rd coupon's image only.  How come it doesn't show the first 2?  Thanks in advance.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    var i: Int = 0
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    CouponsViewController.PopulateDataCoupons()

    i=0
    repeat {
            let imageName = MyCoupons.siteCoupons[i]//"Coupons1.jpg"
            let image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 350, height: 300)
            view.addSubview(imageView)
            i += 1 }
    while (i < MyCoupons.count-1)
}
```

Comment: that's because you put them all on top of eachother (look at their frames) that's why you only see the third one ( the last one that's added ). What you need to do is re-evaulate where exactly you want the three images to appear on the screen and move forward accordingly

Comment: Can u please give me some clue?  I want them to show one after the other.  How do I do this? Do you mean just set new frames for the 2nd one and so on?

Comment: edit: I can't give you a clue on what to do other than changing the x and y of the frame of each image during the loop because I dont know exactly what you are trying to achieve in terms of UI

Comment: you can try this and have a look at what it gives to get a better understanding. *This is by no means the solution*
`imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50 + 300 * i, width: 350, height: 300)`

Comment: thanks.  I changed the frames, now I can see all 3 coupons.

Comment: My question is about pagination next.  What happens if there are more than 3 coupons?  3 coupons showed up in the entire phone, and I couldn't scroll down to see the next few ones.  Any ideas?

Comment: try looking at a scrollview this should solve your problem

Comment: I added a scrollview, with Pagination enabled in scrolling.  It doesn't scroll.  Any other ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should gain a better understanding of scrollview before proceeding they can be fustrating to work at times. Have a look around a few tutorials or try giving different things a shot, go explore and learn and have fun. And if you get stuck post another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting each `UIImageView` object at the same location. Look at this line:

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 350, height: 300)
```

Try changing the `x` or `y` coordinate on each iteration to see each one of the images, like this:

```
let height = 350
i = 0
repeat {
        let imageName = MyCoupons.siteCoupons[i]//"Coupons1.jpg"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: i * height, width: 350, height: height)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        i += 1 
}
while (i < MyCoupons.count - 1)
```

**Update:**

As @Mick MacCallum points out. You should take the UIImageView's height into consideration. See the changes above.

Comment: The image views are still going to overlap like this. The updated origin needs to take the size of the image views into consideration.

Comment: How about scrolling?  I did what was suggested by adding a scrollview but it didn't work.  I already set Pagination to enabled.